# Read document.URL in HTTPS?

Tags: javascript, url, https

I can't read `document.URL` from a page whose protocol is HTTPS.

Example for `alert(document.URL)`:

- on `http://www.example.com`:  `"http://www.example.com"`
- on `https://www.example.com`:  no alert is produced, no errors are reported back to the browser

Comment: Which browser are you using? Do you have any example page? It's working for me on facebook and google, using Chrome.

Comment: Are you actually visiting the page, or are you loading it in an iframe or something similar? Could this be related to the fact that https://www.example.com has an invalid certificate and therefore requires manual user confirmation to proceed?

Comment: It looks as though it's an issue specifically within a not-found URL in IIS.  ie: execute test.html if input URL is not found on server.  If https is the protocol it doesn't read document.URL.  If anyone has had a similar problem and has a workaround i'd love to hear from you.

Comment: example.com is a hypothetical domain name.  The domain name that i'm testing on has a valid certificate.  IIS will execute a page in a 404 not found instance.  If the protocol of that page is https document.url seems to be ignored.